# IE 8 install how to get version 8.0.6001.18702

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I am having trouble installing the latest version of IE namely version 8.0.6001.18702. I downloaded the install from Microsoft but when the install is completed, the version number is reported as IE 8.0.6001.18702IC. This version does not work on all web applications and I need to get the correct final version installed. The problem is compounded by the installation downloading any updates from the Microsoft site so that there is no real control over the final version you get. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is answered at MSDN forum  please check it @ http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/ae1d9fcc-1c97-428f-afc0-13b1f6ad6c9b

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't have a 140 character limit - please post the full URL so that everyone knows exactly where your link is pointing.